# Unsubscribe from a chat group on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, chat

I am getting weekly notifications for a chat group on Stack Overflow, but I want to leave that chat room and I am unable to find that option. Can someone help me with this how to unsubscribe from a chat group.
[image]
Note: This chat room get activated only on weekends.

PS: Can't find the issue tag so adding it to bug

Comment: If you go to the room there is a "leave" option in the right hand sidebar. I don't know whether this will unsubscribe you from notifications though.

Comment: Kids today. No respect. Time was you'd join a chat group and stick with it- in sickness and in health, good times and in bad, flame wars and all- now as soon as you find out the chat room isn't perfect you just drop it like a hot potato. Well, I hope your parents are proud. Incidentally, that's what was so great about AOL back in the day- even if you repeatedly told them you wanted to leave, they knew better.

Comment: @ParthianShot Whaaat?

Comment: @ParthianShot I think you got emotional with it. I have joined this chat by mistake by just seeing the name but now wondering how to opt out from this.

Comment: @ArihantGodha I think Parthian Shot was making a joke.

Comment: It's clearly a joke, and it's pretty funny

Comment: @user3114046 lol. I thought it was an serious one :D

Comment: Should I mark this as bug?

Comment: What is the bug? That you did not click the "leave" button?

Comment: Even after clicking the leave button, I am still the part of the room and still showing the leave link.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean you get notified of a *chat room event* here? If so, see [How do I stop getting notifications for a chat event?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190849)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did that still I am getting these notifications. Even for this I have cancelled my registration from all other chats as well, still no success